# ONVIF Sethostname

Tags: xml, soap, camera, onvif

I'm trying to send a SetHostName request to an ONVIF camera, but I can't make the request correctly and I always get an error.
Please help me.

'''

```
<?xml
        version='1.0'
        encoding='utf-8'
        ?>
     <soap-env:Envelope
        xmlns:soap-env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap-env:Header>
            <wsse:Security
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:UsernameToken>
                    <wsse:Username>
                        admin
                        </wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password
                        Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">
                        gfdsgfsgfsgfs
                        </wsse:Password>
                    <wsse:Nonce
                        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                        fdsgfdsgfsdfgsd
                        </wsse:Nonce>
                    <wsu:Created
                        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        2024-01-17T14:03:35+00:00
                        </wsu:Created>
                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
                </wsse:Security>
            </soap-env:Header>
            <soap-env:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <tds:SetHostname xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
        <tds:HostnameInformation>
        <tt:Name>NewHostname1234</tt:Name>
        </tds:HostnameInformation>
        </tds:SetHostname>
            </soap-env:Body>
        </soap-env:Envelope>'''
```